# Enable OPCache not working in WAMP

Tags: wamp, opcache

I tried to enable OPCache for Drupal 8.0.4 in WAMP 3 but it isn't working. So I googled and changed a few things in my php.ini file and here is what I changed:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

to

```
opcache.enable=1
```

and also

```
opcache.enable_cli=0
```

to

```
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

But still, the '!' mark appears near the PHP Extension. When I try to get the log it says :

```
Sorry,

The 'php_opcache' extension cannot be loaded by 'extension=php_opcache.dll' in php.ini. Must be loaded by 'zend_extension='.

Switch cancelled

Press ENTER to continue...
```

But in the PHP.ini file it says:

```
zend_extension ="C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.0/ext/php_opcache.dll"
```

What else should I do to enable OPCache?

Comment: Possible duplicate..Check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697619/enable-opcache-for-php-in-wamp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to PHP configuration / php.ini file and add these two lines end of the page

zend_extension=php_opcache.dll

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled

opcache.enable=1

You can also increase the max execution time on php.ini configuration file.

max_execution_time=180

Hope it helps.