# wamp installation existing warning for opcache and enchant

Tags: php, wamp, opcache, enchant

I installed the wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b.exe under windows 10. When i start up, i found that the plugin opcache and enchant existing warning flag.

At the same time, I found there php error log:

> [18-Mar-2016 12:40:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on
>   line 0
>
> [18-Mar-2016 12:40:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on
>   line 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The php_enchant extension uses the functions of the [Enchant library](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) by Dom Lachowicz. You need to have this installed. Enchant also requires Glib 2.6 or greater. Pre-compiled Windows libraries are available from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/glib/ or http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/glib/ for 64 bit. See http://php.net/manual/en/enchant.requirements.php

For the php_opcache extension see this post [Enable opcache for php in wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697619/enable-opcache-for-php-in-wamp)